# Opencart reviews submit success message

Tags: opencart

I been trying for hours and cant figure it out, any help will be great :)

I am using OC 1.5.5.

Issue: If a customer submits a product review it wont show a success message like "Thank you for your review. It has been submitted to the webmaster for approval." It does get submitted to the admin and I can see it come through but the customer cannot see any kind of success message.

This is the template I purchased, you can see in the demo what I mean: http://www.templatemonster.com/opencart-templates/43582.html

I have looked through: catalog/language/english/product/product.php and I seen this: $_['text_success'] = 'Thank you for your review. It has been submitted to the webmaster for approval.'; so its there but not working..

I really want to have a popup notification that has a message of success.

If anybody could help me out that will be great, I have done so much research online and cant figure it out. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please, place a review and watch the request and it's response (e.g. using Firefox - either the [Console] or [Net] tab). The response probably contains some other output than just the JSON response. Fix this and You'll be done.

Comment: I tried Mozilla and Safari, both dont work.. Not sure how to find this other file apart from the JSON response, I have looked everywhere.. any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I want to write down *Firebug*, not Firefox. Firebug is developer tool (downloadable extension), but You can use also the default one (both accessed by key F12). Nevermind, I'll do it for You and post the result here...

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like the problem is directly in the template, because the demo of the template receives this JSON response but displays no text to the user as well:

```
{"success":"Thank you for your review. It has been submitted to the webmaster for approval."}
```

It is now upon You to contact the theme developers and ask for support (this may be considered as a **bug**!) or to fix it by Yourself. In the latter case You'd have to open up `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/product/product.tpl` and somewhere at the end (where all the JS scripts are) search for `review` - here an AJAX request is done but probably it does not listen to `success` or `complete` statuses or just does not display the response of the request anywhere.

Your turn.